# Make a POST request to webservice

Tags: java, web-services

I am trying to make a post request to the webservice as it only accept the post request. I have a code as

```
try {
        URL url = new URL(createBookUrl + "?bookInfo=" + jsonStr);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
        String inputLine = in.readLine();
        in.close();
        BookCreateResponse bookCreateResponse = new BookCreateResponse ();
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        bookCreateResponse = mapper.readValue(inputLine, new TypeReference<BookCreateResponse>(){});
        System.out.println(bookCreateResponse );
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        log.error(ex.getMessage());
    }
```

Right now I am getting error

```
Server returned HTTP response code: 405 for URL: .....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with this:

```
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;

    private HttpClient client;
    private HttpPost requestPost;

    client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();


    requestPost = new HttpPost(url+params);
    HttpResponse response = client.execute(requestPost);
    HttpEntity entiry = response.getEntity();
    responseString = EntityUtils.toString(entiry, "UTF-8");
```

Comment: In which package are those HttpPost, HttpResponse , HttpClientBuilder,

Comment: is there special way of adding param? I am getting illegal character at '=' sign as I am creating string as "someUrl?myParam=" + someParam

Comment: in my application i have for example:String action; params = "?action="+action;
  url = url + params;

Comment: I used                                                              List<NameValuePair> postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("action", jsonString));
requestPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(postParameters));